# How Would I get access to a variable from a different class in java?

Tags: java, class, object, variables, javafx

I currently have a variable that I would like to access in a different class but i'm not sure on how I would go about doing so. I have tried doing stuff like `int nums = SizeSelect.amount;` but that has not worked. Here is the code from the class I'm trying to access the amount varaible.

```
public class SizeSelect extends BorderPane {
    public SizeSelect(){
        size8.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new EnterNamesScene());
            int amount = 9;
        });

        size32.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new EnterNamesScene());
            int amount = 33;
        });

        size16.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new EnterNamesScene());
            int amount = 17;
        });
```

and here is the code that I'm trying to access that amount varible

```
public class EnterNames extends BorderPane {
    public EnterNames(){
        int nums = SizeSelect.amount;
        for (int j = 0; j < nums; j++) {
            int teamNum = j + 1;
            TextField test = new TextField();
            test.setPromptText("Enter Team " + teamNum);
            box.getChildren().add(test);
            test.setMaxWidth(500);
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you learn about creating class instances and using instance fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs some information on when and where `EnterNames` is declared, but **assuming** it is done in `EnterNamesScenes`, then one solution would be to first add `amount` as a `EnterNamesScenes` attribute, and then pass directly the value from it as a constructor argument (in `SizeSelect`) and then use it to construct a `EnterNames` instance.

For example :

```
size16.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new EnterNamesScene(17));
}
```

And in `EnterNamesScene` :

```
private int amount;
public EnterNamesScene(int amount){
    this.amount=amount; //this value comes from the button action and will be saved to create a EnterName

    //Constructor stuff
}
```

Then whenever you want to create a `EnterNames` instance, simply add the value of `amount` as an argument :

```
EnterNames en = new EnterNames(this.amount);
```

And the constructor :

```
public EnterNames(int amount){
    for (int j = 0; j < amount; j++) {
    int teamNum = j + 1;
    // Rest of the code
}
```

**NOTE** : As I said before, this will only work in the case where `EnterNames` is created inside `EnterNamesScenes`. Otherwise, you will have to provide more information about how `EnterNames` is instantiated.

Comment: The problem is - so it seems - he tries to use SizeSelect directly and doesn't instatiate it. That way it won't work. The more it looks like a return-statement would help more in this case.

Comment: @Melvin His attempt was to get `amount` directly from `SizeSelect`, this won't work, even with `amount` as a global variable and using a getter, because `EnterNames` should know from **which** instance of `SizeSelect` the amount has been initialized, and this is not possible unless `EnterNames` having a `SizeSelect` attribute which is set to the `SizeSelect` instance where the action has been handled and then sent back to `EnterNames` by setting its attribute with, for example : `setSizeSelect(this)`. But this is clearly a bad design in my opinion.

Comment: @Melvin also, op doesn't provide enough information on how `EnterNames` is instantiated.

Comment: ```public class EnterNamesScene extends Scene {
    public EnterNamesScene(){
        super(new EnterNames(), 1600, 900);
    }

}``` That Is how EnterNames is instantiated

Comment: @TSoVz, I guessed correctly, so my solution should work for you :)

Comment: So I tried it out however I'm getting the error "Cannot reference 'this' before supertype constructor has been called". I tried taking out the super but got another error saying there is no default constructor in javafx

Comment: @TSoVz yes, since `EnterNames` is construct inside `EnterNamesScene`, you don't have to add `amount` as a field, just pass it to the constructor like that : `public class EnterNamesScene extends Scene { public EnterNamesScene(int amount){ super(new EnterNames(amount), 1600, 900); } }`, and from the `SizeSelect` class, call it with the `amount` as argument : `MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new EnterNamesScene(17));`.

Comment: @TSoVz Glad I've helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The amount variable in SizeSelect is local to each onClicked handler, and thus not reachable outside the handler function scope.

If you want to be able to reach SizeSelect.amount, you need to declare it as static in the class.

```java
public class SizeSelect extends BorderPane {
    public static int amount;

    public SizeSelect(){
        size8.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new EnterNamesScene());
            amount = 9;
        });

        size32.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new EnterNamesScene());
            amount = 33;
        });

        size16.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new EnterNamesScene());
            amount = 17;
        });
```

Note that this is a quick fix, the more appropriate solution would be to use a getter/setter. See https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp

Comment: The amount field should probably not be `static`.